# VueJS - i can't hide readmore button before or after reach the selected limit data to show in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i'm using vuejs2. Try to hide the button before or after reach the amount of value, but i can't event get the data length to compare with limit. I try to re-assign it into an array, still not work cause the length is 1. Any idea how to do or different way to do that? Thanks

```js
export default {
  name: 'SlideEvents',
  props: {
    dataEvents: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return []
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      limit: 6
    }
  },
  components: {
    CardSlide
  },
  computed: {
    dataFilter () {
      if (this.dataEvents) {
        return this.dataEvents.slice(0, this.limit)
      } else {
        return this.dataEvents
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid more-top">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card box-simple border-0">
          <h2>Agenda Terbaru</h2>
          <div class="mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-5 mt-2 px-4">
            
              <CardSlide class="mb-4" v-for="each in dataFilter"
              :key="each.id"
              :content="each" />
            </div>
            <button @click="limit*=2">Show More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This may be related with how you set your property `dataEvents`.  Are you getting no items to show up in the list?

Comment: data is show up on the list, the problem is i can't hide the button if that data less than limit. so i wan't to compare the data length with limit in v-if button. i clone the data to array,but i just get the length is 1. original data return is like this {one: value},{two:value},{three: value}.... i've tried all way, and finally it's solve now with this way: I directly clone the data to array in dataFilter with this: const data = [...this.dataNews] n also directly sort the data in the same computed. and then i can get the length and can compare to the limit for button. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

To hide your button, use the `v-if` directive.

```html
<button v-if="dataFilter && dataFilter.length < dataEvents.length" @click="limit*=2">Show More</button>
```

This will only show the button if there are events, and the filtered events are less than the total.

You can also use the `v-show` directive.